# How to Use a Boolean to Compare Action<int>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, callback, boolean, action

I have a method as below

```
public void RequestTPCost(Action<int> callback, Action<int> enemyCallback)
 {
        if (OnTPSelectionNeeded == null)
        {
            callback?.Invoke(0);
            enemyCallback?.Invoke(0);
            return;
        }
        if (TurnSystem.Instance.IsPlayerTurn())
        {
            //Player turn use shooting unit is selected and target is enemy
            OnTPSelectionNeeded?.Invoke(this, new TPSelectionInfo()
            {
                callback = callback,
                enemyCallback = enemyCallback,
                TPAvailable = selectedUnit.GetTacticalPoints(),
                enemyTPAvailable = targetUnit.GetTacticalPoints(),
            });
        }
        else
        {
            OnTPSelectionNeeded?.Invoke(this, new TPSelectionInfo()
            {
                callback = callback,
                enemyCallback = enemyCallback,
                TPAvailable = targetUnit.GetTacticalPoints(),
                enemyTPAvailable = selectedUnit.GetTacticalPoints()
            });
        }
    }
```

and I use it elsewhere like this

```
private void UnitActionSystem_OnTPSelectionNeeded(object sender, UnitActionSystem.TPSelectionInfo e)
    {
        maxTP = e.TPAvailable;
        maxEnemyTP = e.enemyTPAvailable;
        callback = e.callback;
        enemyCallback = e.enemyCallback;
        TPAmount = 1;
        enemyTPAmount = 0;
    }

public void TPConfirm()
    {
        callback?.Invoke(TPAmount);
        UnitActionSystem.Instance.GetSelectedUnit().
                SpendTacticalPoints(TPAmount);
        enemyTPAmount = Random.Range(0, (maxEnemyTP + 1));
        enemyCallback?.Invoke(enemyTPAmount);
        UnitActionSystem.Instance.GetTargetUnit().
                SpendTacticalPoints(enemyTPAmount);
    }
```

```
private void NextState()
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case State.Aiming:
            state = State.Choosing;
            stateTimer = 0.1f;
            UnitActionSystem.Instance.RequestTPCost(ConfirmTPCost, 
            ConfirmEnemyTPCost);
            break;
        case State.Choosing:
            state = State.Shooting;
            float shootingStateTime = 0.1f; //Not a frame
            stateTimer = shootingStateTime;
            break;
        case State.Shooting:
            state = State.Cooloff;
            float coolOffStateTime = 0.5f;
            stateTimer = coolOffStateTime;
            Debug.Log("Shooting");
            break;
        case State.Cooloff:
            ActionComplete();
            break;
    }
}

private void ConfirmTPCost(int value)
{
    Debug.Log($"TP = {value}");

    NextState();
}

private void ConfirmEnemyTPCost(int value)
{
    Debug.Log($"EnemyTP = {value}");

    //NextState();
}
```

Now I want to check if `ConfirmTPCost < ConfirmEnemyTPCost` but am not sure how to simply do that.

I have a roundabout way using events and more `UnityActionSystem` functions to call the instance and work through that but it seems very clunky and prone to breaking. Is there a better way to get these values and check which is more?

Comment: Could you tell us more about what `RequestTPCost` does exactly? Otherwise it will be hard to tell ...

Comment: Sure, I updated it. It references the public struct TPSelectionInfo with the inputs shown which is then put into a selector.

Comment: Still agree with the comments below .. why do those have to be callbacks instead of directly returning values? Is there anything asynchronous involved?

Comment: Yes, the script has to wait for the player and AI to select a value so the callbacks are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cost = 0;
var enemyCost = 0;
UnitActionSystem.Instance.RequestTPCost(i => cost = i, i => enemyCost = i);
Debug.Log($"TP = {cost}");
Debug.Log($"EnemyTP = {enemyCost}");
if (cost < enemyCost)
{
    //Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It shows both costs as zero and then stops.

Comment: Check your RequestTPCost method that it calls provided Actions with desired values.

Comment: The values do get chosen but the state machine they are attached to doesn't go to the next state. Originally, ConfirmTPCost ran NextState() but all of it is now within NextState().

Comment: I've omitted call to NextState(). You should provide more context to get help.

Comment: I added the complete NextState() method as more context.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using Action<T> callbacks instead of just returning two values in tuple instead. This could make sense in async flow, but in this case it looks like unnecessary complexity. You need to read more about functional programming and become more familiar with it, to understand what to do next.

Comment: The callbacks are running in a selector for the player and AI to choose values, so the event to choose gets triggered in UnitActionSystem which goes to the selector which then sends those values to NextState which is part of the action script being done.

Comment: Sounds to me like there is indeed something asnychronous involved so the code gets executed before both callbacks are finished .. it is not even enough to wait for only one of them but basically you either need to actually get into async - await coding or combine both into a single callback

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As said it sounds like there is actually some asynchronous parts involved.

So you either will want to properly implement `async` and `await` patterns and wait for both values to be available.

Or alternatively you could somewhat fake that behavior using e.g. nullables and a local function ike

```
int? cost = null;
int? enemyCost = null;

UnitActionSystem.Instance.RequestTPCost(i => 
{
    cost = i;
    if(enemyCost != null)
    {
        Validate();
    }
}, i =>
{
    enemyCost = i;
    if(cost != null)
    {
        Validate();
    }
});

// Can be a local function 
// otherwise pass in the two int values via parameters  
void Validate()
{
    Debug.Log($"TP = {cost.Value}");
    Debug.Log($"EnemyTP = {enemyCost.Value}");
    if (cost.Value < enemyCost.Value)
    {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Idea here: No matter which of both callbacks fires first, it is ignored and only for the second one both values are already available and the actual handler method can be invoked

Comment: I am able to have the method wait already for the selection by the player. The problem is I don't know how to get the int value out of the action<int> in order to compare which is more. Your proposed solution works at first but then breaks down upon repeat usage. It starts to run twice when it should be once as shown here [link](https://youtu.be/DBBwTVbWFPg)

Comment: I don't know anything about how your code works or what exactly I am looking at in your video I'm afraid... `The problem is I don't know how to get the int value out of the action<int> in order to compare which is more` well O guess that would be how but I don't know how your system invokes those callbacks exactly... Seems to accumulate them somewhere

Comment: I added how the callbacks are being used in the selector.

Comment: I suggest you set up breakpoints and [Debug](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) where exactly those two callas come from and what is causing them to be invoked twice - for instance you could e.g. try to immediately reset them `callback = null; enemyCallback = null;` within `TPConfirm` to make sure they can only be called again after being setup again first .. though I'd rather focus on why `TPConfirm` is called again then ;)

Comment: Also seeing now that basically both callbacks are triggered together anyway ... we are kinda back to the first question why you provide those as individual callbacks in the first place .... why not just have a single combined `Action<int, int>` then?

Comment: I tried `Action<int, int>` at first and it didn't work so I made two separate ones. Perhaps because the player does one action and then the AI another? Not sure. But this still goes back to my original question of how to get the `int` values out and compare them because I can't compare `Action<int>` with another.

Comment: as said .. you assign them to something, wait for both actions to finish then compare both values ... you issue seems to rather be the multiple invocations so I would focus my debugging on that ;)

Comment: `Perhaps because the player does one action and then the AI another?` .. I don't know ^^ it's your code ... the code you provided doesn't seem so .. you invoke both within the same synchronous context `TPConfirm` .. I don't see a reason why `Action<int, int>` wouldn't work for that ...

Comment: The code I posted works how I want it to. That's not the issue. What I need is to know how to compare the `int` values inside `Action<int>` when the code is done.  I want to check if `ConfirmTPCost < ConfirmEnemyTPCost` when `UnitActionSystem.Instance.RequestTPCost(ConfirmTPCost, 
            ConfirmEnemyTPCost)`. Would `Action<int, int>` allow that? I don't want to mess with code I know works when I don't need to.

Comment: Well in `Action<int, int>` you could add a single callback method `private void Validate(int cost, int enemy cost){ if(cost < enemy cost){ whatever (); } }` .. that's why I'm suggesting it. Either way you somehow have to make sure you have both values until you handle them. I just say that because in your code I see no reason why both callbacks need to be separated if they are called together anyway. Without changing too much you could have it additional as optional parameter `Action<int, int> combined callback = null` then you can but don't have to provide one

Comment: This way you don't have to change everything in your code but only add an additional field to your handlers and only in the case where you need both values together you use that callback instead of the first two